# Validate TelephoneNumber PHP

Tags: php, validation

I was given a task to validate a telephone number (stored in the var $number) introduced by a user in my website

```
$number = $_POST["telephone"];
```

The thing is this validation is quite complex as i must validate the number to see if it is from Portugal. i thought about validating it using all the indicators from Portugal, which are 52: (50 indicators are 3 digits long and 2 indicators are 2 digits long) Example of a number:

254872272 (254 is the indicator)

i also thought about making an array with all the indicators and then with a cycle verificate somehow if the first 2/3 digits are equal to the ones in the array.

what do you guys think? how should i solve this problem?

Comment: Let's back up just a second. Do you want to check that it's an *apparently valid number* (in that it's the right length of digits, correctly formatted or whatnot), or that *it's a real number you can dial*? Usually validating phone numbers comes down to the former; if the number is bogus, that's up to the user.

Comment: the number being 9 numbers long is not a problem i already got that covered with maxLength in the textbox, what i wanna validate is if the number the user writes is a Portuguese number even if the number is not real

Comment: You can't trust what you get from the browser, so you need to validate the length and content on the *server*; what you do on the *client* (browser) is only an assist for the user, it is unreliable. However, you can do something like this: http://codepad.org/zesUaxF7 Note the use of strings and not integers in both `$indicators` and `$numbers`; this is so that `072` will be evaluated correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's potential REGEX ways of "solving" this, but really, all you need is `in_array()` with your indicators in an `array`. For example:

```
$indicators = array('254', '072', '345');

$numbers = array(
    '254872272',
    '225872272',
    '054872272',
    '072872272',
    '294872272',
    '974872272',
    '345872272'
);

while ($number = array_shift($numbers)) {
    $indicator = substr($number, 0, 3);

    if (in_array($indicator, $indicators)) {
        echo "$number is indicated ($indicator).\n";
    } else {
        echo "$number is NOT indicated ($indicator).\n";
    }
}
```

http://codepad.org/zesUaxF7

This gives:

```
254872272 is indicated (254).
225872272 is NOT indicated (225).
054872272 is NOT indicated (054).
072872272 is indicated (072).
294872272 is NOT indicated (294).
974872272 is NOT indicated (974).
345872272 is indicated (345).
```

Also, I use strings instead of integers on purpose, since PHP is going to interpret any numbers that begin with `0` (like `0724445555`) as not having a leading zero, so you need to use a string to make sure that works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use regular expressions with named subpatterns:

```
$number = 254872272;
$ind = array( 251, 252, 254 );

preg_match( '/^(?<ind>\d{3})(?<rest>\d{6})$/', $number, $match );

if ( isset($match['ind']) && in_array( (int) $match['ind'], $ind, true ) ) {
    print_r( $match );
    /*
    Array
    (
       [0] => 254872272
       [ind] => 254
       [1] => 254
       [rest] => 872272
       [2] => 872272
    )
    */
}
```

Or you can insert indicators directly into regular expression:

```
preg_match( '/^(?<ind>251|252|254)(?<rest>\d{6})$/', $number, $match );
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with a regular expression?

I have not tested the following, but it should check for one of the matching indicators, followed by any 6 digits, something like:

```
$indicators = array('123' ,'456', '78'); // etc...

$regex = '/^(' . implode('|', $indicators) . ')[0-9]{6}$/';

if(preg_match($regex, 'your test number')) {
  // Run further code...
}
```

Comment: The question mentioned the indicators may be 2 or 3 digits long, the accepted answer will not correctly match 2 digit indicators and will also potentially give false positive matches when a 2 digit indicator is followed by another digit 0-9.  See http://codepad.org/2ma5SekC

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of libraries around that aim to validate as many telephone number formats as possible against the actual validation format, as defined by the relevant authorities.

They are usually based on a library by Google, and there are [versions for PHP](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php).